# Using the UCANACCESS_HOME system property with LibreOffice Base and UCanAccess

Tags: shell, parameters, ucanaccess, libreoffice-base

I am trying to use LibreOfffice Base to access an MS Acccess database using UCanAccessv3.0.1 on Lubuntu. Everything is fine until I get an error message about the UNCANACCESS_HOME system variable. In spite of correctly entering the path, I get a message saying

> "the system variable UCANACCESS_HOME doesn't point to the correct ucanaccess home"

I'm not sure whether this is a typo or a something else. The path used is

```
/home/mike/Software/UCanAccess-3.0.1-bin/
```

which is where the UCanAccess was extracted to.

Any thoughts? Does it dislike full stops? Tried leaving off the last / but didn't make any difference.

**Update re: comments**

To answer your queries in order:

Etan: I'm setting it using the nice instructions here: http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html

Jamadei: working down from the top level, rights are `rwxrwxr-x` for the directories and `rw-rw-r-` for the jars.

Gord: No folders within folders.

Comment: Where are you setting that variable? Are you setting it *before* running libreoffice?

Comment: Are you sure the extraction was successful? Do you see a lib directory with 4 jars under /home/mike/Software/UCanAccess-3.0.1-bin/lib? Have you already  checked the rights on /home/mike/Software/UCanAccess-3.0.1-bin/ and  /home/mike/Software/UCanAccess-3.0.1-bin/lib and on the contained jars?

Comment: `-DUCANACCESS_HOME=/home/gord/Downloads/JDBC/UCanAccess-3.0.1-bin` works for me, both with and without a trailing slash, so it's not an issue with periods (full stops) in the path. Check that when you did the extraction you didn't end up with a folder-within-a folder (e.g.,  "/home/mike/Software/UCanAccess-3.0.1-bin/UCanAccess-3.0.1-bin/".

Comment: Your question says "I get an error message about the UNCANACCESS_HOME system variable". Double-check the spelling in the `-D` command; it should be `UCANACCESS_HOME`, not `UNCANACCESS_HOME`.